# C# MVC Bind variables in a string to model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, properties

In `C# MVC` you can use model binding to automatically parse variables to a model.

```
public class RegistrationForm {
 string Name {get;set;}
 string Address {get;set;} 
}

public ActionResult Register(RegistrationForm register) {
...
}
```

If I pass the `Name` and `Address` variables they are directly available in the `register` object.

Is it possible to call this binding manually if you have the variables in a string?
EG:

```
var s = "name=hugo&address=test";

//dosomething to get RegistrationForm register

//register.Name == hugo
```

I know I can get a `NameValueCollection` with `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(s);` and then use reflection to get the properties of `RegistrationForm` and check if the values exists, but I was hoping I could use the actually binding method MVC uses.

Comment: Please, if you edit my question dont change it's meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could mock the HttpContext passed into Modelbinding like here

http://www.jamie-dixon.co.uk/unit-testing/unit-testing-your-custom-model-binder/

```
var controllerContext = new ControllerContext();
//set values in controllerContext  here
var bindingContext = new ModelBindingContext();
var modelBinder = ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder;
var result = modelBinder.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext)
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I needed. Unfortunately that is even more (A lot more, actually) work then using reflection. I'm basically building a whole new page request from scratch to bind the values.

Answer (score 1):

MVC binding working based on Property Names of your `ViewModel` (`RegistrationForm` class).

So you absolutely right, if you use **GET** HTTP Method to bind your property from string you can write this directly:

> http://yourSite.com/YourController/Register?Name=hugo&Address=test

It's case sensitive, be carefull.

Or if you use Razor to generate links you can write it more clear way:

```
@Url.Action("Register", new { Name = "hugo", Address = "test"})
```

Comment: Yes I know I'm right :) But I don't get the values from the query string or POST, I have them in a string variable. They edited my question wrongfully.

Comment: ok, you mean in `js` variable? You can also do it with `js`. `window.location.href = 'http://yourSite.com/YourController/Register?'+s;` but don't forget about case.

Comment: @teovankot: No, a C# string.

Comment: No, I mean a `string myvariables = "name=hugo&address=test"` I'm already in a controller/action and there I have variable which I want to parse to a model

Comment: and you can't change this string at all?

Comment: Yes I can, what do you want me to do with it?

Comment: can you show code where you get this string? i mean js code or html or else where you compose it? It's much simplier to change your code there. If you can't change it there from where it come from you really should use `Reflection` like you menthion or try to change some variables in `Context` and try to call your `Action` with changed `Context` whitch is not much better and maby worse in the perfomance way than `Reflection`.

Comment: I dont agree with "It's case sensitive"

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string to JSON object and then you can parse JSON object to your Model by using a Serializer.

Answer (score 0):

@Malcolm's anwser is what I requested, so he gets the credits. But I still ended up doing it with reflection, because it looks a lot cleaner in my opinion and easier to understand what is going on.

```
var result = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(strResponse);
Type myType = GetType();
IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(myType.GetProperties());
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
{
    try
    {
        prop.SetValue(this,
            Convert.ChangeType(result[prop.Name], prop.PropertyType, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            null);
    }
    catch (InvalidCastException)
    {
        //skip missing values
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //something went wrong with parsing the result
        new Database().Base.AddErrorLog(ex);
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer**
This works for me because I only get strings and decimals and nothing is required. This is nothing like the MVC model binder.